# Linq Any() side effects

Tags: c#, linq

If reflector is right (and I tend to believe it is), this is the implementation for Any():

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (e.MoveNext()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

From my understanding, `MoveNext()` moves the underlying enumerator by one position and therefore, calling `Any()` multiple times can have an adverse effect on "shrinking" the collection.

I tried to reproduce this with a `List<>` but I wasn't able to do this, yet, I'm unable to find out what `List<>` does differently to address this problem.

My simple example to verify `List<T>` works correctly with multiple `Any()` calls:

```
var meh = new List<string> {"1", "2"};
var enumerable = meh.AsEnumerable();
bool any = enumerable.Any(); //true
any = enumerable.Any(); //true
any = enumerable.Any(); //true but isn't it meant to have "moved" the enumerator by two positions already?
any = enumerable.Any(); //true
```

So my questions are:

1. Am I correct in understanding that `Any()` does indeed have side effects on the `Enumerable`
2. If so, how does `List<>` circumvent it?

Sorry if it's a dumb question in advance. Just something that I found very interesting.

Comment: The enumerator is disposed in your implementation, so it always starts at the beginning. Actually it is the .NET source as you can see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8788153112b7ffd0,references).

Comment: Although, you could make an implementation of `IEnumerable` where `GetEnumerator`/`MoveNext` have side effects - this would make all Linq methods have side effects as well.

Comment: @SWeko That's why I asked the question in the first place. I was receiving an `IEnumerable<>` from a third party API and by calling `Any()`, the sequence was shrinking but I wasn't able to reproduce it with the existing `.Net` collections and I couldn't understand why they didn't have the same side effects but I now understand better.

Comment: @kha - do a `.ToList()` on the received thing and you should be safe.

Comment: Yeah, the API is returning a non-conforming enumerable then :) Each time you start iterating an enumerable, you should get a new enumerator, and the enumerator should have no side effects. Once you break this, a lot of things just stop working properly. There's a reason why most of the C#'s functional-programming-like code tends to use immutable data and avoids side-effects - it just doesn't fit well together.

Comment: @SWeko Yep. That's what I ended up doing (although I probably want to create a new lazy collection type since I may run into memory issues soon). Just wanted to understand why that collection was doing it and why List<> wasn't. I understand it now and have raised a bug report for them to have a look at their implementation and fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to the `using` statement the enumerator is disposed, so it always starts at the beginning. The enumerator is also always created from `source.GetEnumerator()` and not reused. Actually this is the .NET source as you can see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8788153112b7ffd0,references).

The same is true for the other overload of [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It enumerates the sequence until the predicate matches, then it will be disposed.

This method is also not using deferred execution(it lacks the `yield` keyword). Therefore it is always executed immediately.

Comment: It's not even the `Dispose()` call, it's the `source.GetEnumerator()` call which makes sure that a new enumerator is used every time.

Comment: @Vilx- Yeah, it's not because you're disposing the old enumerator, it's *because you get a new one every time*.

Comment: @Tim Exactly. If you can't reuse the old enumerator, why do you care that it's disposed? Even if the old enumerator wasn't disposed, `Any` would still start from the beginning every time. The fact that the enumerator is disposed is irrelevant.